# Removing space between span and paragraph in email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to write code for email, which is why I'm using tables and inline styles.

I'd like to remove the space between my `span` and `p`.  I don't know why it's there in the first place.

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <span valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" class="content" style="  font-family: 'Lato',Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 19px; line-height:35px; color: #654308;> Header Goes Here </span>
      <p font-family: 'Lato',Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:200; font-size: 16px; color: #654308;>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod. </p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: adding  `margin-top:0px;` to your `p` tag will do it and enclose the styling inside a `style="styling goes here"` for that `p` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the space between `span` and `p` reset  `margin` in `p` to `0` (`p{margin:0}`), since it has some `margin` by default. ( if you are using it to build a [html-email](/questions/tagged/html-email) then apply it inline

**NOTE**

you have 2 errors:

- you are missinng `"` in your `span` here:  `#654308;> Header`
- you are missing `style` attribute in `p` before the `font-family`

```css
p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" class="content" style="  font-family: 'Lato',Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 19px; line-height:35px; color: #654308;"> Header Goes Here </span>
      <p style="font-family: 'Lato',Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:200; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #654308;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Regarding Support: Outlook.com will be the only one not supporting `margin`, check [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for more info

Comment: Quick note on margin: Outlook.com doesn't support `margin` but it [supports `Margin`](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/outlook.com-does-support-margins). Go figure. But Outlook.com is being replaced with Office365, which _does_ support `margin`.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <span valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" class="content" style="  font-family: 'Lato',Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 19px; line-height:35px; color: #654308;"> Header Goes Here </span>
      <p style="margin:0px; font-family: 'Lato',Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:200; font-size: 16px; color: #654308;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod. </p>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is weird you do not use a header when you are styling a span to be a header and you have some typos in your code above.

You need to remove the default margin-top from the paragraph

```
td>p { margin-top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 0 margin to both the span and the p.  Take a look here:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <span bgcolor="#fff" class="content" style= "font-family: Lato, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-weight:700;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height:35px;
  color: #654308;
  margin-bottom: 0;"> Header Goes Here </span>
      <p style="  font-family: Lato,Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:200; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #654308; margin-top: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod. </p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

margin-bottom: 0 on your span and margin-top: 0 on your p will remove the space.

See a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/0d2tv8wp/1/

Also, since you are using table elements for an html email, make sure that you use the correct inline style formatting. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, <p> elements with have margins around them by default. You could try adding "margin: 0" to your <p>'s styles.

HOWEVER, be aware different email clients may vary greatly in default styles and in which parts of CSS they pay attention to (Outlook.com will ignore margins unless the 'm' at the start of 'margin' is capitalized: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/outlook.com-does-support-margins). I'd recommend testing your email in a service like Litmus, which lets you see how it looks on a variety of clients.

Also, here's a handy list of which CSS features are supported by various email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.

Comment: In my experience, even capitalizing the M doesn't actually make outlook read 'margin' tags, when I use litmus.com but I don't have an actual PC that uses outlook in order to check.  Thank you for the help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, **replace the `<p>` and `<span>` tags with `<table>` markup:**

```
<tr>
   <td  valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" class="content" style="font-family: Lato, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 19px; line-height:35px; color: #654308;> Header Goes Here </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-family: Lato, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:200; font-size: 16px; color: #654308;"">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod.
   </td>
</tr>
```

Messing with the `margin` and `display` properties will work in many email clients (and maybe the ones your targeting), but using `<table>` tags is much safer if you want the best compatibility and don't care about the semantics of `<p>` and `<span>` tags.